# Devise + RSpec - Validation Errors for Registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am currently implementing an API for the first time using Rails and I am running into some unexpected errors when doing request tests using RSpec. As of now, I have verified that my model and controller are properly set up as I was able to `POST` to the database using `curl` as follows:

`curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/v1/users -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"user1@example.com\",\"password\":\"somepassword\",\"password_confirmation\":\"somepassword\"}}"`

Unfortunately, when I am making the same requests from my RSpec tests, the server is returning with an error stating that the email has already been taken. The only thing is that this error makes no sense as I am using Faker to create emails and DatabaseCleaner to clean the test database. Here is my setup, and a copy of the log of my tests.

`registrations_controller.rb`:

```
class Api::V1::Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  respond_to :json

  def create
    build_resource (user_params)

    if resource.save
      sign_in resource
      render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Registered",
                      :data => { :user => resource,
                                 :auth_token => resource.authentication_token } }
    else
      render :status => :unprocessable_entity,
             :json => { :success => false,
                        :info => resource.errors,
                        :data => {} }
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

`spec/factories/user.rb`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  password =  Faker::Internet.password(10)

  factory :user do |user|
    user.email { Faker::Internet.email }
    user.password { password }
    user.password_confirmation { password }
  end
end
```

`spec/api/v1/user/user_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'POST /v1/users' do
  it "allows new users to register with an email address and password" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

    post '/v1/users', {
      user: {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
        password_confirmation: user.password_confirmation
      }
    }.to_json, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                 'Accept' => 'application/json' }

    puts response.body

  end
end
```

And the server response is as follows: `{"success":false,"info":{"email":["has already been taken"]},"data":{}}`. I have tried everything to fix this issue, but unfortunately have failed. Can anyone spot an error in my implementation? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already creating the user in database with

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) ## Creates a user record in database
```

and then trying to *register the same user* (create the same user by registration via `Api::V1::Users::RegistrationsController#create`) which is why you receive the error as:

```
"email":["has already been taken"] ## due to uniqueness constraint on email
```

What you need to do is simply build an instance of User class using FactoryGirl as:

```
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user) ## Use "build" (which builds an instance of User) and NOT "create" method
```

and let the registration method i.e., `Api::V1::Users::RegistrationsController#create` take care of *User creation*.

Comment: Thank you so much Kirti. You are right! Using build instead of create did it form me. Kudos to you!